# Domain management by other hosting provider

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I have one domain in Australia, named mydomain.id.au , but the hosting company does not provides me with Domain management at all.
Actually i want to get rid of my local domain name server, running on my machien, i want to migrate it to some other domain manager.

Is it possible that i can use Domain management features of other domain manager for my site? for example, of NameCheap or Godaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of companies that will provide DNS hosting; some for free, some for a nominal fee, and some for an exorbident amount of money.  We don't give specific shopping recommendations here, though, as the answers get out of date too quickly, and trying to deduce your specific needs is a lengthy question-and-answer process that doesn't help anyone but you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that i can use Domain management features of other domain manager for my site?

Yes, it's possible. Location of host in domain and ns-servers of domains are unrelated things. You have to have only *always correct data* about NSes in *registar records*